# Saving results to a text file

Tags: java, arrays, format, save

I'm working on a dice rolling project at the moment and would like to save my project to a .txt or .pdf file so I can graph it in excel. I just learned how to save a program as a file in my computer science class but I have a difficult time understanding my professor sometimes. Could someone point out what I'm missing and possibly explain the concept a little bit? I've tried to google some sort of explanation but all I need is the barebones explanation on how to save it to a file.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Lab1 {

    private static int N = 0;
    private static int M = 0;
    private static Random rnd = new Random();   
    private final static int FACENUMBER = 6;
    static String output = "output.txt";
    static File file = new File(output);

    public Lab1(){

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        N = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many dice would you like to roll?"));
        System.out.println("Dice: "+N);

        M = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many times would you like to roll?"));
        System.out.println("Rolls: "+M);

        System.out.println();

        int total[] = new int[(M)+1];

        for (int roll=1; roll<=M; roll++){
            total[roll] = rnd.nextInt((FACENUMBER-1)*N)+N;
        }

        System.out.printf("%3s%12s\n", "Rolls","    Sum of Rolls");

        for(int k=1; k<total.length; k++){

            System.out.printf("%3s%12s\n", k, total[k]);
        }
        try{
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        writer.write(output);
        writer.close();

        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Can't open "+output);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean you want to save the dice results to a file? at the moment this creates a file called output.txt that contains output.txt

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't specify. I want to save the results to a file.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to write to writer, you try to pass output as a variable:

```
try{
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        writer.write(output);
        writer.close();
}
```

However, output is your text file.

So you need to create a String variable that takes the results from your for loop:

```
for(int k=1; k<total.length; k++){

            System.out.printf("%3s%12s\n", k, total[k]);
        }
```

Instead you could use the following:

```
String yourString=""; //Empty string
    for(int k=1; k<total.length; k++){

               yourString=yourString + "%3s%12s\n" + k + total[k];
   }
```

Then instead of using:

```
writer.write(output)
```

use:

```
writer.write(yourString);
```